# WiFi management tool to monitor a mobile device

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I am setting up a Linux based Wireless Access Point.

I am using `hostapd` command in Ubuntu. Once set up, I will connect the Mobile device.

I am looking for a management tool in Linux or Windows to monitor the Mobile Device. I am particularly interesting in recording the RSSI value.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like munin might provide what you want, it will run every 5 minutes and save off values to later graph.  I see there is an [RSSI plugin](http://exchange.munin-monitoring.org/plugins/brc_rssi/details) that might do what you want.  If not, writing plugins is very easy.

Comment: Thanks, I installed the munin, looks very promising,but the RSSI plugin suggested doesnt work.. This plugin works mainly with Broadcom wireless chipsets. I had a look at the script. I am not aware of the commands for the D-Link Wireless card.  Any suggestions.. ??

Comment: No idea...  Have you looked at the documentation that comes with the drivers for that card?  Or searched google?  Sorry I can't be of more help with that, I don't know that card at all.